# Animating a series of images at multiple places using threads

Tags: image, animation, scheme, racket

I am trying following code:

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image)

; list of images to be animated: 
(define images (list (circle 30 "outline" "red")
                     (circle 20 "outline" "red")
                     (circle 10 "outline" "red")
                     (circle  5 "outline" "red")))

(define (image->bitmap image)   ;from: https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-December/065110.html
  (let* ([width (image-width image)]
         [height (image-height image)]
         [bm (make-bitmap width height)]
         [dc (send bm make-dc)])
    (send dc clear)
    (send image draw dc 0 0 0 0 width height 0 0 #f)
    bm))

(define frame (new frame% [label "Frame"] [width 300] [height 300]))
(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]))
(define a-dc (send canvas get-dc))

(send frame show #t)
(sleep/yield 1)


(define x 20)
(define y 20)

(define (thunk)
  (let loop ()  ; endless loop
    (for ((i images))
      (send a-dc draw-bitmap (image->bitmap i) x y)
      (sleep 0.5)) 
    (loop)))

(thread thunk) 

(set! x 100)
(set! y 100)
(thread thunk)

(set! x 200)
(set! y 200)
(thread thunk)
```

However, only third animation runs while others show only the largest circle (first image). Apparently, previous threads also take new x and y values. How can I have them preserve initially sent x and y values? I cannot have any argument in thunk function because it has to be sent to thread function that needs an argument-less function argument!  (I hope my complex statement/argument is functionally correct).

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread is referring to the same x and y coordinates. This means all threads are drawing at the same place.

Here is an example that shows that having two different sets of x and y variables work.

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image)

; list of images to be animated: 
(define images (list (circle 30 "outline" "red")
                     (circle 20 "outline" "red")
                     (circle 10 "outline" "red")
                     (circle  5 "outline" "red")))

(define (image->bitmap image)   ;from: https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-December/065110.html
  (let* ([width (image-width image)]
         [height (image-height image)]
         [bm (make-bitmap width height)]
         [dc (send bm make-dc)])
    (send dc clear)
    (send image draw dc 0 0 0 0 width height 0 0 #f)
    bm))

(define frame (new frame% [label "Frame"] [width 300] [height 300]))
(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]))
(define a-dc (send canvas get-dc))

(send frame show #t)
(sleep/yield 1)


(define x 20)
(define y 20)

(define (thunk)
  (let loop ()  ; endless loop
    (for ((i images))
      (send a-dc draw-bitmap (image->bitmap i) x y)
      (sleep 0.5)) 
    (loop)))

(thread thunk) 

(define X 100)
(define Y 100)

(define (thunk2)
  (let loop ()  ; endless loop
    (for ((i images))
      (send a-dc draw-bitmap (image->bitmap i) X Y)
      (sleep 0.5)) 
    (loop)))

(thread thunk2)
```

Rather than having variables for each coordinate, consider storing them in a data structure (for example a hash table) and letting the threads read the coordinates from the data structure.

It would be simpler to have a single drawing function that draws all objects at once.

However if you want multiple threads, then use a function to create the thunk:

```
(define (make-thunk n) 
   (lambda () 
     (let loop () ... )))
```

use `n` to pick out the coordinates of the n'th object ...)) Then create the threads with `(thread (make-thunk 0)) (thread (make-thunk 1))`

Comment: Hence one needs to write separate thunk function for each position, even if rest of the code is essentially same. Can there be some way to use have a common function?

Comment: The simplest is to have a drawing function that draws all objects at once. If you want multiple threads, then use a function to create the thunk:  `(define (make-thunk n) (lambda () (let loop () ... use n to pick out the coordinates of the n'th object ...))` Then create the threads with  `(thread (make-thunk 0)) (thread (make-thunk 1))` etc.

Comment: Yes, a function to create thunk fn, e.g. (make-thunk n) or (make-thunk x y), is what I was looking for. It will be great if you can add this to your answer above.

Comment: @rnso Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer by @soegaard I found following `animateImageList` fn to be very convenient for showing a list of images at multiple places and with different speeds:

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image)

(define (image->bitmap image)   ;from: https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2014-December/065110.html
  (let* ([width (image-width image)]
         [height (image-height image)]
         [bm (make-bitmap width height)]
         [dc (send bm make-dc)])
    (send dc clear)
    (send image draw dc 0 0 0 0 width height 0 0 #f)
    bm))

(define (animateImageList imglist sent-dc x y secs) 
  (λ ()
    (let loop ()  
      (for ((i imglist))
        ;(send sent-dc clear)  ; this may be added to clear previous image; 
        (send sent-dc draw-bitmap (image->bitmap i) x y)
        (sleep secs)) 
      (loop))))

(define imglist (list (circle 40 "outline" "yellow")
                      (circle 30 "outline" "red")
                      (circle 20 "outline" "blue")
                      (circle 10 "outline" "green")
                      (circle  5 "outline" "black")))

(define frame (new frame% [label "Frame"] [width 300] [height 300]))
(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]))
(define a-dc (send canvas get-dc))
(send frame show #t)
(sleep/yield 1)

(thread (animateImageList imglist a-dc 10  10  0.1))
(thread (animateImageList imglist a-dc 100 100 0.4))
(thread (animateImageList imglist a-dc 200 200 0.7))
```

Output:

[image]